# Rails select_tag css with options_from_collection_for_select

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, forms

I have a form_tag in Rails as below:

```
    <%= form_tag(listings_path, method: :get) do %>
      What 
      <%= text_field_tag :title, "",class: 'form-control' %>

      Category
      <%= select_tag(:category_id, options_from_collection_for_select(Category.all, :id, :name), { :prompt => 'All Categories' }) %>

      Area 
      <%= select_tag(:area, options_for_select(['All', 'Ireland', 'UK']), class: "form-control") %>

      <%= submit_tag 'Search', name: nil, class: "btn btn-primary" %>
    <% end %>
```

Where should I add the CSS option >> class: "form-control" << for the Area field to have it working? I tried few options I found on SO but no luck

Comment: I'm sorry, my mistake. I need to do this for the Category field. Area is working fine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I set it up just a little bit different than you in my apps but this works.

```
...

<% options = options_from_collection_for_select(Category.all, :id, :name) %>
<%= f.select :category_id,  options, class: "form-control", :include_blank => 'All Categories' %>

...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<%= select_tag "area", options_for_select(['All', 'Ireland', 'UK']), :include_blank => '--Choose an option--', class: 'form-control' %>
```

Answer (score -1):

Go to **App>>assets>>stylesheet**s and post in any of the scss pages